# How can you get information such as, users window for example using the NSTask class in Swift, for OSX apps?

Tags: swift, nstask

If I can explain my self better knowing if a user is running some particular program such as word or chrome, etc.

I will try to update my question as I write code or find more information.

Thank you (:

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to go through `NSTask`, you can use Cocoa's `NSWorkspace` to get the list of running applications:

```
import Cocoa
let apps = NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace().runningApplications
```

It returns an array of `NSRunningApplication` objects.

Let's say you want the running applications names in an array:

```
let appsNames = apps.flatMap { $0.localizedName }
```

If you want to know for example if iTunes is running:

```
if appsNames.contains("iTunes") {
    // iTunes is running
}
```

Note, a more precise way to find a running app would be to use the bundle identifier:

```
let bundleNames = apps.flatMap { $0.bundleIdentifier }
if bundleNames.contains("com.apple.iTunes") {
    // iTunes is running
}
```

If you want to know which app is active (has its window frontmost):

```
let actives = apps.filter { $0.active }
if let active = actives.first {
    // "active" is the frontmost app
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much