# Terminal command not recognised?

Tags: macos, swift3

when I type this directly into the terminal - it works as expected and returns **0** if the app is not running, and **1** if it is.

lsappinfo list | grep -v grep | grep bundleID | grep com.test.myapp | wc -l

However, when I use the code below (swift 3 - macOS), it says it is an unrecognised command?

```
// DECLARE TASK
    let task = Process()

    // DEFINE THE PATH
    task.launchPath = "/usr/bin/lsappinfo"

    // DEFINE THE ARGUMENTS
    task.arguments = ["list | grep -v grep | grep bundleID | grep com.test.myapp | wc -l"]

    // DECLARE outputPipe
    let outputPipe = Pipe()

    // RUN THE TASK
    task.launch()

    // DECLARE data
    let data = outputPipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()

    // DECLARE output AS THE UTF-8 STRING OF THE TERMINAL'S OUTPUT
    let output = NSString(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
        print(output!)

    if output == "0" {
        print("App is not running!")

    } else {
        print("App is running!")
    }

    // PAUSE UNTIL COMPLETED
    task.waitUntilExit()
```

Can someone please tell me where I have gone wrong, as I am new to Swift, and still struggling to get my head around the language / syntax.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Have a look at `NSWorkspace` and its `runningApplications` method for a possibly easier solution. Example here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37646605/how-can-you-get-information-such-as-users-window-for-example-using-the-nstask-c.

Comment: Thanks Martin -that worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

Piping operations are not arguments to the process, they are instructions to a shell to connect several separate processes. If the task construct in swift expects a process and a set of command-line argument, then one way to do this here would maybe be to launch the bash binary, and then put `-c "lsappinfo list | grep -v grep | grep bundleID | grep com.test.myapp | wc -l"` as the full set of arguments. That way, you would let bash sort out what's needed to accomplish the piping.

Comment: You beat me to it!

Comment: @cnettel, I had already tried as you suggested, but that gives me the same error message.  I simply need to check if an external app is running, I will look into Martin. R's solution, and see if I can work out how to do it that way.  Thank you both!